# Opentext Extended ECM Custom column Workspace Name fr not found

Tags: opentext

Hi everyone I'm new to extended ecm !
Whenever I try to open the (Project) Workspace Tile from the Smart View I get this red error message:

```
Custom column Workspace Name fr not found.
```

I tried to remove french from the system

Comment: Can you describe, precisely, what you did to `remove french from the system` ?